# Tamil Input Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, unicode, internationalization

Hi I would like to create a JTextField which is capable of accepting unicode and displaying corresponding tamil font in it. I have created two arrays for unicode mapping like,

String tam[] = { "ள்", "ளௌ", "ளோ", "ளொ", "ளை", "ளே", "ளெ", "ச்", "சௌ",
                "சோ", "சொ", "ளூ", "ளு", "சை", "ளீ", "சே", "ளி", "செ", "ளா",
                "சூ", "சு", "சீ", "சி", "சா", "ல்", "லௌ", "லோ", "லொ", "லை",
                "லே", "லெ", "ங்", "ஙௌ", "ஙோ", "ஙொ", "லூ", "லு", "ஙை", "லீ",
                "ஙே", "லி", "ஙெ", "லா", "ஙூ", "ஙு", "ஙீ", "ஙி", "ஙா", "ஹ", "ஸ",
                "ஷ", "ற்", "வ", "றௌ", "ழ", "றோ", "ள", "றொ", "ல", "ற", "றை",
                "ர", "றே", "ய", "றெ", "ம", "றூ", "ப", "று", "ன", "றீ", "ந",
                "றி", "றா", "த", "ண", "ட", "ஞ", "ஜ", "ச", "ங", "ர்", "ரௌ", "க",
                "ஔ", "ரோ", "ஓ", "ரொ", "ஒ", "ரை", "ஐ", "ரே", "ஏ", "ரெ", "எ",
                "ரூ", "ஊ", "ரு", "உ", "ரீ", "ஈ", "ரி", "இ", "ரா", "ஆ", "அ",
                "ஃ", "ய்", "யௌ", "யோ", "யொ", "யை", "யே", "யெ", "யூ", "யு",
                "யீ", "யி", "யா", "ம்", "மௌ", "மோ", "மொ", "மை", "ஸ்ரீ", "மே",
                "மெ", "க்", "கௌ", "கோ", "கொ", "மூ", "மு", "கை", "மீ", "கே",
                "மி", "கெ", "மா", "கூ", "கு", "கீ", "கி", "கா", "ப்", "பௌ",
                "போ", "பொ", "பை", "பே", "பெ", "பூ", "பு", "பீ", "பி", "பா",
                "ன்", "னௌ", "னோ", "னொ", "னை", "னே", "னெ", "னூ", "னு", "னீ",
                "னி", "னா", "ந்", "நௌ", "நோ", "நொ", "நை", "நே", "நெ", "நூ",
                "நு", "நீ", "நி", "நா", "த்", "தௌ", "தோ", "தொ", "தை", "தே",
                "தெ", "தூ", "து", "தீ", "தி", "தா", "ண்", "ணௌ", "ணோ", "ணொ",
                "ணை", "ணே", "ணெ", "ணூ", "ணு", "ணீ", "ணி", "ணா", "ஹ்", "ஹௌ",
                "ஹோ", "ஹொ", "ஹை", "ஹே", "ஹெ", "ஹூ", "ஹு", "ஹீ", "ஹி", "ஹா",
                "ஸ்", "ஸௌ", "ஸோ", "ஸொ", "ஸை", "ஸே", "ஸெ", "ட்", "டௌ", "டோ",
                "டொ", "ஸூ", "ஸு", "டை", "ஸீ", "டே", "ஸி", "டெ", "ஸா", "டூ",
                "டு", "டீ", "டி", "டா", "ஷ்", "ஷௌ", "ஷோ", "ஷொ", "ஷை", "ஷே",
                "ஷெ", "ஞ்", "ஞௌ", "ஞோ", "ஞொ", "ஷூ", "ஷு", "ஞை", "ஷீ", "ஞே",
                "ஷி", "ஞெ", "ஷா", "ஞூ", "ஞு", "ஞீ", "ஞி", "ஞா", "வ்", "வௌ",
                "வோ", "வொ", "வை", "வே", "வெ", "ஜ்", ",", "ஜௌ", "ஜோ", "ஜொ",
                "வூ", "வு", "ஜை", "வீ", "ஜே", "வி", "ஜெ", "வா", "ஜூ", "ஜு",
                "ஜீ", "ஜி", "ஜா", "ழ்", "ழௌ", "ழோ", "ழொ", "ழை", "ழே", "ழெ",
                "ழூ", "ழு", "ழீ", "ழி", "ழா" };

```
    String eng[] = { "s;", "nss", "Nsh", "nsh", "is", "Ns", "ns", "r;",
            "nrs", "Nrh", "nrh", "Sh", "S", "ir", "sP", "Nr", "sp", "nr",
            "sh", "R+", "R", "rP", "rp", "rh", "y;", "nys", "Nyh", "nyh",
            "iy", "Ny", "ny", "q;", "nqs", "Nqh", "nqh", "Y}", "Y", "iq",
            "yP", "Nq", "yp", "nq", "yh", "*", "*", "qP", "qp", "qh", "`",
            "]", "\\", "w;", "t", "nws", "o", "Nwh", "s", "nwh", "y", "w",
            "iw", "u", "Nw", "a", "nw", "k", "W}", "g", "W", "d", "wP",
            "e", "wp", "wh", "j", "z", "l", "Q", "[", "r", "q", "u;",
            "nus", "f", "xs", "Nuh", "X", "nuh", "x", "iu", "I", "Nu", "V",
            "nu", "v", "\\&", "C", "U", "c", "uP", "<", "up", ",", "uh",
            "M", "m", "\"", "a;", "nas", "Nah", "nah", "ia", "Na", "na",
            "A+", "A", "aP", "ap", "ah", "k;", "nks", "Nkh", "nkh", "ik",
            "=", "Nk", "nk", "f;", "nfs", "Nfh", "nfh", "%", "K", "if",
            "kP", "Nf", "kp", "nf", "kh", "$", "F", "fP", "fp", "fh", "g;",
            "ngs", "Ngh", "ngh", "ig", "Ng", "ng", "G+", "G", "gP", "gp",
            "gh", "d;", "nds", "Ndh", "ndh", "id", "Nd", "nd", "D}", "D",
            "dP", "dp", "dh", "e;", "nes", "Neh", "neh", "ie", "Ne", "ne",
            "E}", "E", "eP", "ep", "eh", "j;", "njs", "Njh", "njh", "ij",
            "Nj", "nj", "J}", "J", "jP", "jp", "jh", "z;", "nzs", "Nzh",
            "nzh", "iz", "Nz", "nz", "Z}", "Z", "zP", "zp", "zh", "`;",
            "n`s", "N`h", "n`h", "i`", "N`", "n`", "`_", "{`", "`P", "`p",
            "`h", "];", "n]s", "N]h", "n]h", "i]", "N]", "n]", "l;", "nls",
            "Nlh", "nlh", "]_", "]{", "il", "]P", "Nl", "]p", "nl", "]h",
            "^", "L", "B", "b", "lh", "\\;", "n\\s", "N\\h", "n\\h", "i\\",
            "N\\", "n\\", "Q;", "nQs", "NQh", "nQh", "\\\\_", "\\{", "iQ",
            "\\P", "NQ", "\\p", "nQ", "\\h", "*", "*", "QP", "Qp", "Qh",
            "t;", "nts", "Nth", "nth", "it", "Nt", "nt", "[;", ">", "n[s",
            "N[h", "n[h", "T+", "T", "i[", "tP", "N[", "tp", "n[", "th",
            "[_", "[{", "[P", "[p", "[h", "o;", "nos", "Noh", "noh", "io",
            "No", "no", "*", "O", "oP", "op", "oh" };
```

Now i want to convert unicode to equivalent tamil character in JTextField while typing. Please Direct me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with just changing the `Font` of the `JTextField`?

Comment: Also, you should probably use a `DocumentFilter`, see [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more details.  Any recommendations to use a `KeyListener` are wrong on so many leaves, I just thought I'd preempt those answers before they appear

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try this out.